# Update SUM Formula by Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Working on Excel VBA to automate daily report, need to update the SUM formula below:

=SUM(B9:B33)+SUM(C3:C33)

The ideal result is to update the formula "B9" part that would move one row down automatically everyday based on the previous day formula. Searched Google but seems only can find the code about replacing certain part of the formula.

Thanks for Gary's answer posted yesterday and I have tried the code in Macro, but showing the Run-Time error 13 Type Mismatch for "I = CInt(Replace(Replace(f,S,""), T, "") + 1". Wondering how to solve that? Thanks for the help!

```
Sub formulaupdate()

Dim R as Range, S as String, T as String, I as Integer

Set R = Range("B34")
    S = "SUM(B"
    T = ":B33)+SUM(C3:C33)"
    f = R.Formula
    I = CInt(Replace(Replace(f,S,""), T, "") + 1

    R = S + I + T
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you currently setting this formula using code?

Comment: @norie Yes I am trying to update the formula using code since it is part of the report. the formula listed is for the first day, then I want the B9 to become B10 then B11 as days going by.

Comment: Is there a column that has the dates that you can leverage to know where to start?

Comment: CAn you post the code?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes there is column for each date within a month, like Sep-01. Sep-02 etc.